# How to add multiple column to c3 gauge chart

Tags: javascript, gauge, c3

I use c3.js for charts and I want to add multiple columns to gauge chart like this

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#gauge",
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data', 75.0],
            ['data2', 66]
        ],
        type: 'gauge',
    },
    gauge: {
        min: 50,
        max: 100
    }
});
```

I created example on jsfiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/L8s9jbw3/).
I want to show percentage only on mouse hover on data.
Any help? Thanks.

Edit.

I found some "hacky" solution. I hide and show value manually. Are there any another solution?

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: "#gauge",
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data', 75.0],
        ['data2', 66]
    ],
    type: 'gauge',
    onmouseover: function (d, i) {
            jQuery('.c3-focused > .c3-gauge-value').show();
            console.log("onmouseover", d, i);
        },
    onmouseout: function (d, i) {
            var selector = 'g[class*="' + d.id  + '"]';
            jQuery(selector).find('text').hide();
            console.log("onmouseout", d, i);
        }
},
gauge: {
    min: 50,
    max: 100
}
});

jQuery('.c3-gauge-value').hide();
```

Comment: That seems perfectly reasonable to me. The two column objects will create two `c3-gauge-value`-classed `text` elements, so you need to hide them both and then show & hide on mouseover, as you've done. You could use D3 to do this but Jquery works just as well. There don't appear to be any settings on the C3 site that would give you what you want, out the box.